# Where is the definition of full binary tree in Isabelle/HOL？

Tags: binary-tree, isabelle

I want to define a full binary-tree in Isabelle/HOL. I only found the definition of a complete binary tree. I want to know where there is a definition of a full binary-tree or how should it be defined in Isabelle/HOL?

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean by full (as opposed to complete). What is your current definition attempt? What exactly is it that you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)

> A full binary tree (sometimes referred to as a proper or plane binary tree) is a tree in which every node has either 0 or 2 children.

You could define this in Isabelle like this:

```
datatype tree = 
      Empty 
    | Node (left:tree) (elem:nat) (right:tree)

fun full where
  "full Empty = True                                          ― ‹Not sure - is the empty tree full?›"
| "full (Node Empty x Empty) = True                           ― ‹Case for 0 children›"
| "full (Node l x r) = (l≠Empty ∧ r≠Empty ∧ full l ∧ full r)  ― ‹Case for 2 children›"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how do you define the thread binary-tree?@peq

Comment: Are you referring to the threaded binary tree (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/threaded-binary-tree/)? That is more complex, since it is not a simple inductive datatype and involves pointers. You can model data structures with pointers using a partial function from addresses to records as representation for the heap.